# Prevent OpenGL from clearing

Tags: android, opengl-es

I have a OpenGL WallpaperService in Android and what I am trying to achieve is adding (drawing) something to scene without losing what I've already draw. For now I am only working with primitives such as triangles, but still can't achieve my goal. Here is my code:

**Renderer:**

```
@Override
public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig config) {
    // Set the background color to black ( rgba ).
    gl.glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.5f);
    // Enable Smooth Shading, default not really needed.
    gl.glShadeModel(GL10.GL_SMOOTH);
    // Depth buffer setup.
    gl.glClearDepthf(1.0f);
    // Enables depth testing.
    gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    // The type of depth testing to do.
    gl.glDepthFunc(GL10.GL_LEQUAL);
    // Really nice perspective calculations.
    gl.glHint(GL10.GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT,
            GL10.GL_NICEST);
}

@Override
public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height) {
    // Sets the current view port to the new size.
    gl.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
    // Select the projection matrix
    gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_PROJECTION);
    // Reset the projection matrix
    gl.glLoadIdentity();
    // Calculate the aspect ratio of the window
    GLU.gluPerspective(gl, 45.0f,
            (float) width / (float) height,
            0.1f, 100.0f);
    // Select the modelview matrix
    gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_MODELVIEW);
    // Reset the modelview matrix
    gl.glLoadIdentity();
}

@Override
public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
    // Clears the screen and depth buffer.
    //gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL10.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    // Replace the current matrix with the identity matrix
    gl.glLoadIdentity();
    // Translates 10 units into the screen.
    gl.glTranslatef(0, 0, -10);

    // SQUARE A
    // Save the current matrix.
    gl.glPushMatrix();
    // Rotate square A counter-clockwise.
    gl.glRotatef(angle, 0, 0, 1);
    // Draw square A.
    square.draw(gl);
    // Restore the last matrix.
    gl.glPopMatrix();

    // SQUARE B
    // Save the current matrix
    gl.glPushMatrix();
    // Rotate square B before moving it, making it rotate around A.
    gl.glRotatef(-angle, 0, 0, 1);
    // Move square B.
    gl.glTranslatef(2, 0, 0);
    // Scale it to 50% of square A
    gl.glScalef(.5f, .5f, .5f);
    // Draw square B.
    square.draw(gl);

    // SQUARE C
    // Save the current matrix
    gl.glPushMatrix();
    // Make the rotation around B
    gl.glRotatef(-angle, 0, 0, 1);
    gl.glTranslatef(2, 0, 0);
    // Scale it to 50% of square B
    gl.glScalef(.5f, .5f, .5f);
    // Rotate around it's own center.
    gl.glRotatef(angle*10, 0, 0, 1);
    // Draw square C.
    square.draw(gl);

    // Restore to the matrix as it was before C.
    gl.glPopMatrix();
    // Restore to the matrix as it was before B.
    gl.glPopMatrix();

    // Increse the angle.
    angle++;
}
```

**Square:**

```
public Square() {
    // a float is 4 bytes, therefore we multiply the number if
    // vertices with 4.
    ByteBuffer vbb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(mVertices.length * 4);
    vbb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
    mVertexBuffer = vbb.asFloatBuffer();
    mVertexBuffer.put(mVertices);
    mVertexBuffer.position(0);

    // short is 2 bytes, therefore we multiply the number if
    // vertices with 2.
    ByteBuffer ibb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(mIndices.length * 2);
    ibb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
    mIndexBuffer = ibb.asShortBuffer();
    mIndexBuffer.put(mIndices);
    mIndexBuffer.position(0);
}

/**
 * This function draws our square on screen.
 * @param gl
 */
public void draw(GL10 gl) {
    // Counter-clockwise winding.
    gl.glFrontFace(GL10.GL_CCW);
    // Enable face culling.
    gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_CULL_FACE);
    // What faces to remove with the face culling.
    gl.glCullFace(GL10.GL_BACK);

    // Enabled the vertices buffer for writing and to be used during
    // rendering.
    gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    // Specifies the location and data format of an array of vertex
    // coordinates to use when rendering.
    gl.glVertexPointer(3, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, mVertexBuffer);

    gl.glDrawElements(GL10.GL_TRIANGLES, mIndices.length,
            GL10.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, mIndexBuffer);

    // Disable the vertices buffer.
    gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    // Disable face culling.
    gl.glDisable(GL10.GL_CULL_FACE);
}
```

Right now it shows 3 squares rotating around different points in space. But I don't want to clear it, so basicaly it shold create a circle after 360° rotation.

Answer (score 1):

OpenGL ES (or actually EGL) works in the way that after a frame has been "swapped", the contents of the frame is undefined. If you want to only do an update, you will need to set the the swap behaviour to EGL_BUFFER_PRESERVED. I think calling the code below in onSurfaceCreated should enable this (not tested):

```
eglSurfaceAttrib(eglGetCurrentDisplay(), eglGetCurrentSurface(), EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOUR, EGL_BUFFER_PRESERVED);
```

Comment: I am working with GL10 class from javax.microedition.khronos.opengles package. GLSurfaceView have a few methods similar to what you mentioned, but not that one. Even Google doesn't know where it might be. Can you be more specified pls?

Comment: You can find these functions in [android.opengl.EGL14](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/opengl/EGL14.html)

Comment: Yes, well first of all it requires API lvl 17... that seems to me really hardcore for such a small thing like preventing clearing... it should be like one time parameter somewhere... don't tell me that the other way is to remember all paths my object have made and draw them in each frame.... there has to be easier way

Comment: You are thinking of this the wrong way - the flag is not about preventing clearing, but rather about **copying** the result from the previous frame. You cannot draw on top of it because **the display driver is using it**.

A way around this is to render what you are drawing to a texture and then for each frame render that texture to the screen.

Comment: Still looks pretty unnecessery to me, but thanks for a solution, looks simple enought. With 2D graphics I am wondering if using canvas wouldn'T be a better option...